# Run animation every x seconds with delay at at begining and every each iteration

Tags: css, css-animations

I have an HTML button I want to spin.
I need it to start spinning after 5 seconds.
when it starts spinning, it does it for 2 seconds and stops for 5 seconds and after that start spinning again for 2 seconds and stop for 5 seconds and so on forever.
How can I do that? I looked for some suggestions but I couldn't find a proper solution.
Here is my code, 400ms must be kept because it is the speed of the spinning:

```
 #register_event{
   animation: wiggle 400ms 3s 8 ease-out none;
 }


 @keyframes wiggle{
   0%{
     transform: rotateZ(0);
   }

   50%{
     transform: rotateZ(-10deg);
   }

   100%{
     transform: rotateZ(10deg);
  `enter code here` }
 }
```

Comment: **400ms**  is not a speed, it is a `animation-duration` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Infinite in CSS to specify that you want to run that animation again and again.
So, change your code to this:

```css
 #register_event{
   animation: wiggle 400ms 3s 8 ease-out none infinite;
 }


 @keyframes wiggle{
   0%{
     transform: rotateZ(0);
   }

   50%{
     transform: rotateZ(-10deg);
   }

   100%{
     transform: rotateZ(10deg);
  }
 }
```

Now, since I don't know the specific order of the shorthand property `animation` just try to put that `infinite` here and there in the line. And it will work perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

the trick to get that delay between 2 runs is to insert a keyframe which just does nothing (the 60% one in my example) so the 40% that follows from that point dont do anything compared to the 0%.

```
@keyframes wiggle{
    0%{
        transform: rotateZ(0);
    }
    
    25%{
        transform: rotateZ(-10deg);
    }
    
    50%{
        transform: rotateZ(10deg);
    }
    60%{
        transform: rotateZ(0deg);
    }
}


#register_event{
    animation: wiggle 2s infinite;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

you get the first delay with animation-delay. dont forget to have it running infinite.
in order to get the right duration you might need to change the keyframe % and the duration of the whole animation (just a bit math), but Im sure you understand the trick!

Comment: Not helping me.

Comment: you tried it? it starts spinnig after 2 sek, spins it, waits a while and then starts spinning again. OK, I know, you want 5sek, and 400ms, but thats only some math... the trick stays the same... here is a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/v782mt3p/